# Can someone help me passing a function as argument in python?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, arguments

I have the following class in python. I want to pass the function get_priority as argument to access the object Task. I obtain the following error when adding the second task to taskManager:

> if value == array[int(middle)].acessMethod(): AttributeError: Task
>   instance has no attribute 'acessMethod'

Task Class

```
class Task:

    def __init__(self,id,name,category="",priority=1):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.priority = priority
        self.concluded = False
        self.active_days = 0
        print("Beggining Class")

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_category(self):
        return self.category

    def get_priority(self):
        return self.priority

    def set_name(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def set_category(self,category):
        self.category = category

    def set_priority(self,priority):
        self.priority = priority

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " | " + self.name + " | " + self.category + " | " + str(self.priority) + " | "
```

TaskManager Class

```
from task import Task

class TaskManager(object):
    """docstring forTaskManager."""

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initing TaskManager")
        self.taskArray = []

    """Adding task ordered by priority"""
    """Maibe adding a check for autheticity of the object """
    def addTask(self,task):
        if len(self.taskArray) == 0 or self.taskArray[0].get_priority() <= task.get_priority():
            self.taskArray.insert(0,task)
        else:
            index = self.__binarySearchIndex(task.get_priority,self.taskArray,'get_priority')
            self.taskArray.insert(index,task)

    def __binarySearchIndex(self,value,array,acessMethod):
        middle = (len(self.taskArray) / 2) if ((len(self.taskArray) % 2) == 0) else (len(self.taskArray) / 2) + 1
        if middle == 1:
            middle = 0
        if value == array[middle].acessMethod():
            return middle
        elif value < array[middle].acessMethod():
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[:middle])
        else:
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[middle:])

    def __str__(self):
        taskString = ""
        for task in self.taskArray:
            taskString = taskString + str(task) + " \n"
        return taskString
```

Comment: You `Task` class doesn't need so many unnecessary getters and setters. Access the attribute directly until there is some need for protected access, at which point you can replace them with properties without affecting existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually went another way instead of calling the method by its name, I simply make a lambda function to extract whatever attribute I want from the Task object.

```
class Task:

    def __init__(self,id,name,category="",priority=1):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.priority = priority
        self.concluded = False
        self.active_days = 0
        print("Beggining Class")

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_category(self):
        return self.category

    def get_priority(self):
        return self.priority

    def set_name(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def set_category(self,category):
        self.category = category

    def set_priority(self,priority):
        self.priority = priority

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " | " + self.name + " | " + self.category + " | " + str(self.priority) + " | "

class TaskManager(object):
    """docstring forTaskManager."""

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initing TaskManager")
        self.taskArray = []

    """Adding task ordered by priority"""
    """Maibe adding a check for autheticity of the object """
    def addTask(self,task):
        if len(self.taskArray) == 0 or self.taskArray[0].get_priority() <= task.get_priority():
            self.taskArray.insert(0,task)
        else:
            index = self.__binarySearchIndex(task.get_priority(),self.taskArray, lambda task: task.get_priority())
            self.taskArray.insert(index,task)

    def __binarySearchIndex(self,value,array,accessMethod):
        if len(array) == 0:
            return 0
        middle = (len(self.taskArray) / 2) if ((len(self.taskArray) % 2) == 0) else (len(self.taskArray) // 2) + 1
        if middle == 1:
            middle = 0
        if value == accessMethod(array[middle]):
            return middle
        elif value < accessMethod(array[middle]):
            return middle + self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[:middle],accessMethod)
        else:
            return middle - self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[middle:],accessMethod)

    def __str__(self):
        taskString = ""
        for task in self.taskArray:
            taskString = taskString + str(task) + " \n"
        return taskString

if __name__ == "__main__":
    taskA = Task(1, "taskA", priority=2)
    taskB = Task(2, "taskB", priority=1)
    taskC = Task(3, "taskC", priority=1)
    taskD = Task(4, "taskD", priority=3)
    manager = TaskManager()
    manager.addTask(taskA)
    manager.addTask(taskB)
    manager.addTask(taskC)
    manager.addTask(taskD)
    for task in manager.taskArray:
        print(task)
```

I've also helped debug your program a little. For starters, your recursive calls to the binary search doesn't return values, which is a behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use getattr to get the function from the string you pass

```
method_to_call = getattr(Task, accessMethod)

if value == array[middle].method_to_call():
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a string containing the name at all. Use the `methodcaller` function.

For example:

```
from operator import methodcaller


class TaskManager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.taskArray = []

    def addTask(self, task):
        if (len(self.taskArray) == 0
            or self.taskArray[0].get_priority() <= task.get_priority():
            self.taskArray.insert(0,task)
        else:
            index = self.__binarySearchIndex(
                task.get_priority(),
                self.taskArray,
                methodcaller('get_priority')
            )
            self.taskArray.insert(index, task)

    def __binarySearchIndex(self, value, array, accessMethod):
        middle = (len(self.taskArray) / 2) if ((len(self.taskArray) % 2) == 0) else (len(self.taskArray) / 2) + 1
        if middle == 1:
            middle = 0
        if value == accessMethod(array[middle]):
            return middle
        elif value < accessMethod(array[middle]):
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[:middle])
        else:
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[middle:])

    ...
```

If you simplify your `Task` class to get rid of the unnecessary getters and setters:

```
class Task:

    def __init__(self,id,name,category="",priority=1):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.priority = priority
        self.concluded = False
        self.active_days = 0
        print("Beggining Class")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " | " + self.name + " | " + self.category + " | " + str(self.priority) + " | "
```

then you can use `attrgetter` instead of `methodcaller`.

```
from operator import attrgetter

class TaskManager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.taskArray = []

    def addTask(self, task):
        if (len(self.taskArray) == 0
            or self.taskArray[0].get_priority() <= task.get_priority:
            self.taskArray.insert(0,task)
        else:
            index = self.__binarySearchIndex(
                task.get_priority, 
                self.taskArray,
                attrgetter('get_priority')
            )
            self.taskArray.insert(index, task)

    def __binarySearchIndex(self, value, array, accessMethod):
        middle = (len(self.taskArray) / 2) if ((len(self.taskArray) % 2) == 0) else (len(self.taskArray) / 2) + 1
        if middle == 1:
            middle = 0
        if value == accessMethod(array[middle]):
            return middle
        elif value < accessMethod(array[middle]):
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[:middle])
        else:
            self.__binarySearchIndex(value,array[middle:])

    ...
```